# Modify JSON property text dynamically

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON array, that I want to modify dynamically using PHP, but don't know how to. Searched online, but couldn't find what I needed. 
Here is my code

```
{"objects":[{"type":"text","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":46.05,"top":129.71,"width":412.09,"height":52,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1.33,"scaleY":1.33,"angle":352.36,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"red","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","text":"companyName","fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Delicious_500","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.3,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"left","path":null,"textBackgroundColor":"","useNative":true}],"background":""}
```

Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Actually I am using FabricJS JavaScript library for canvas manipulation. The code above represents a canvas code that draws something onto the canvas. I have to modify the text dynamically.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring out whatever it is you want to do, because we obviously can't - you haven't explained what you want to do at all.

Comment: php's native json_decode?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php   then just treat it like an array or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution handles the fact that the given JSON string is **not** valid (`companyName` is not enclosed in strings), that's why in this particular case, it is not possible to use `json_decode()`:

```
$string = '{"objects":[{"type":"text","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":46.05,"top":129.71,"width":412.09,"height":52,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1.33,"scaleY":1.33,"angle":352.36,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"red","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","text":companyName,"fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Delicious_500","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.3,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"left","path":null,"textBackgroundColor":"","useNative":true}],"background":""}';

$newString  = preg_replace('/("text"):(companyName)/', '${1}:"Acme Ltd."', $string);

// To check if the string is now valid JSON, will return a PHP array
print_r(json_decode($newString, true));
```

**Update** (after Badar has fixed the JSON)

The fastest solution would be this:

```
$json = '{"objects":[{"type":"text","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":46.05,"top":129.71,"width":412.09,"height":52,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1.33,"scaleY":1.33,"angle":352.36,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"red","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","text":"companyName","fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Delicious_500","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.3,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"left","path":null,"textBackgroundColor":"","useNative":true}],"background":""}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$data['objects'][0]['text'] = 'New text';

$newJson = json_encode($data);

echo $newJson;
```

Comment: I encloded companyName in double quotes.